# ASP.NET Core 7 MVC : extend cookie duration when page change

Tags: .net-core, asp.net-core-mvc, asp.net-core-7.0

I am developing a project with .NET 7. In this project, I keep cookie information with the following code.

```
services.AddDistributedMemoryCache();

services
     .AddAuthentication(options =>
            {
                options.DefaultScheme = CookieAuthenticationDefaults.AuthenticationScheme;
            })
     .AddCookie(options =>
            {
                options.ExpireTimeSpan = TimeSpan.FromMinutes(Configuration.Instance.sessionTimeOut.TotalMinutes);
                options.SlidingExpiration = true;
                options.LoginPath = "/Login/Index";
                options.Cookie.Name = "my_app_auth_cookie";
                options.Cookie.HttpOnly = true;
                options.Cookie.SameSite = SameSiteMode.None;
                options.Cookie.SecurePolicy = CookieSecurePolicy.None;
                options.Cookie.MaxAge = options.ExpireTimeSpan;
                options.Cookie.IsEssential = true;
            });
```

As a result of this code, the cookie information looks like this:

[Cookie info](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fC6YI.png)

I want the cookie duration to increase as the page changes, but it always stays the same and kicks the user out when the time runs out. How can I extend the duration as the page changes?

```
services.AddDistributedMemoryCache();
services
     .AddAuthentication(options =>
            {
                options.DefaultScheme = CookieAuthenticationDefaults.AuthenticationScheme;
            })
     .AddCookie(options =>
            {
                options.ExpireTimeSpan = TimeSpan.FromMinutes(Configuration.Instance.sessionTimeOut.TotalMinutes);
                options.SlidingExpiration = true;
                options.LoginPath = "/Login/Index";
                options.Cookie.Name = "my_app_auth_cookie";
                options.Cookie.HttpOnly = true;
                options.Cookie.SameSite = SameSiteMode.None;
                options.Cookie.SecurePolicy = CookieSecurePolicy.None;
                options.Cookie.MaxAge = options.ExpireTimeSpan;
                options.Cookie.IsEssential = true;
            });
```

When I try the code above, the cookie duration remains the same even if the page changes.

Comment: Since you've set SlidingExpiration to true ,a new cookie with a new expiration time any time it processes a request which is more than halfway through the expiration would be set up,or you want to refresh the cookie even if it has expired when you refresh the page?